# Searching value of array inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following object:-

```
var list = {
  nums: [
    [117],
    [108]
  ],
  numsset: [
    [2256, 2265],
    [234],
    [3445, 3442]
  ]
};
```

If I had an input field on the page where a customer typed a number, how would I then be able to search the object for that value and return the key eg.

```
Input      Returned
108        nums
3445       numsset
2872       
2265       numsset
```

I have attempted looping through, but it didn't produce the required result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thank you in advance.

Comment: "_I have attempted looping through, but it didn't produce the required result._" Show us that code and what it produced any maybe we can help you edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```js
const list = {
  nums: [
    [117],
    [108]
  ],
  numsset: [
    [2256, 2265],
    [234],
    [3445, 3442]
  ]
};

const findElement = (value) => {
  let foundKey = '';
  
  Object.keys(list).some((key) => {
    const array = list[key];
    
    const found = array.some(element => element.includes(value));
    
    if (found) {
     foundKey = key;
      return true;
    }
    
    return false;
  })
  
  return foundKey;
}

console.log(findElement(2256));
console.log(findElement(108));
console.log(findElement(222));
```

Comment: ilsotov, how difficult would it be to change the code to say if it input starts with one of the values. E.g findElement(22562) would still return numsset as it starts with 2256.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a hash table and store the keys of the given numbers.

```js
var list = { nums: [[117], [108]], numsset: [[2256, 2265], [234], [3445, 3442]] },
    keys = {};

Object.keys(list).forEach(k => list[k].forEach(a => a.forEach(v => keys[v] = k)));

console.log(keys);
```